# x11vnc session with virtual display results in grey screen

Tags: vnc

Sooooo, I've scoured the entire inter webs for a solution for this but no luck so far, so this is pretty much my last resort :')

There is no display attached to the computer so I open a display session with "vncserver :0"
On my rPi O could open displays using "xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1600x900" but it doesn't work here.

Anyways when I connect to my computer after opening a display with "vncserver :0" I get a grey checkered screen.
Does anyone have an idea as to what I did wrong ?

Many thanks :)

Comment: I'm confused - where does `x11vnc` fit in here? that's for relaying a real desktop. If you are just trying to configure VNC with the desktop session of your choice (in place of the default gray background + Xterm) I have found this guide useful in the past: [VNC/Servers - Customising your session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#Customising_your_session)

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that you could use x11vnc with a virtual desktop.
Ill try your guide :)